# Creating an event from Last Imported in Photos.app

Tags: macos, photos.app

How do I make an event from my last import using Photos? Does Photos only use albums rather than events? Is it still possible to merge events?

Answer (score 1):

Photos uses Albums instead of Events and you can create an Album from the last imported by selecting all in the Last Imported album and clicking the **+** icon on the toolbar. Albums are merged by selecting the contents of one, copying it to another, then deleting the first.